# PostgreSQL: Inserting tuples in multiple tables using a view and a trigger

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, sql-view

I am trying to build an order system that is able to insert a compound order that consists of multiple items and amounts. My database layout is as follows: I have an `order` table, containing an autoincrement `id`, `item_id`, `amount` and `order_group_id` columns. I also have an `order_group` table containing an autoincrement `id` and a `person_id` column. The idea is that when a person orders, one new `order_group` entry is created, and its `id` is used as the fk in the `orders` that the person has done.

I presume that this would normally be done in the code of the application. However, I am using postgrest to provide an API for me, which suggests creating a custom view to insert compound entries via that route. This is described [here](https://postgrest.org/en/v3.2/api_writing.html#multiple-tables-insertion-or-update).

This is what I have so far:

```
CREATE FUNCTION kzc.new_order()
RETURNS TRIGGER
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
    DECLARE
        group_id int;
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO kzc.order_group (person) VALUES (new.person) RETURNING id AS group_id;
        INSERT INTO kzc."order" (item, amount, order_group) VALUES (new.item_id, new.amount, group_id);
        RETURN new;
    END;
$$;

CREATE TRIGGER new_order
INSTEAD OF INSERT ON kzc.new_order
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE FUNCTION kzc.new_order()
```

However, this code makes a new `ordergroup` for every `order` that is in the compound insert. How can I make it so that my code only makes one new `ordergroup` entry and assigns its `id` to all orders?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The problem is that the different rows in multi-value insert have very little in common except the current transaction ID. You might be better off with a function which takes an array of rows as input (but then you cannot simply insert in your view). Maybe you can find other things that identify a group of new rows that belong together.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Would storing a timestamp be a decent solution then? That would mean getting rid of the order_group table, and then grouping by timestamp when we want to query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you add an `order_group_id` column to the `new_order` view and create a sequence for it. Then create a `DEFAULT` value for the column:

```
ALTER VIEW kzc.new_order
   ALTER order_group_id SET DEFAULT currval('order_group_id_seq');
```

Add a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger `FOR EACH STATEMENT` that just calls `nextval` for the sequence. The `currval` calls will all pick up the same generated value.

Then you have that number in your trigger and can use it as a primary key for `order_group`.

To avoid adding the row multiple times, use

```
INSERT INTO kzc.order_group (id, person)
   VALUES (NEW.order_group_id, NEW.person)
   ON CONFLICT (id) DO NOTHING;
```

Comment: Sorry for all the questions, I feel like im very close now. I've updated my trigger and view to include a group_id. The question I still have is: How would I insert a default value from a sequence on the view level?

Comment: Thanks so much! However, it seems that this solution, when presented with a multi-tuple insert, still generates a new `order_group` for every `order`. Any other idea's?

Comment: After much fiddling I have finally got it working! Thanks a bunch!